# How to add a row, which is a sum of some values in a column based on specific values in other column?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I am trying to add two rows to the data frame.

Regarding the first row, its value in `MODEL` column should be `X`, `total_value` should be the sum of `total value` of rows, with the `MODEL` being `A` and `C` and `total_frequency` should be the sum of `total_frequency` of rows, with the `MODEL` being `A` and `C`.

In the second row, the value in `MODEL` column should be `Z`, `total_value` should be the sum of `total_value` of rows, with the `MODEL` being `D`, `F`and `E`, and `total_frequency` should be the sum of `total_frequency` of rows, with the `MODEL` being `D,F`and `E`.

I am stuck, as I do not know how to select specific values of `MODEL` and then sum these two other columns.
Here is my data

```
data.frame(MODEL=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), total_value= c(62, 54, 78, 38, 16, 75, 39, 13,  58, 37),
 total_frequency = c(78, 83,  24, 13, 22, 52, 16, 16, 20, 72))
```

Comment: Hi it seems your data aren't complete.

Comment: You need to do subsetting, try e.g. `sum(dat[dat$MODEL %in% c("A", "C"), "total_value"])`. Read `?Extract`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `dplyr`, calculating the "new rows", then put together with the data `df`:

```
library(dplyr)
first <- df %>%
        # select the models you need
        filter(MODEL %in% c("A","C")) %>%
        # call them x
        mutate(MODEL = 'X') %>%
        # grouping
        group_by(MODEL)  %>%
        # calculate the sums
       summarise_all(sum)

# same with the second
second <- df %>%
         filter(MODEL %in% c("D","F","E")) %>%
         mutate(MODEL = 'Z') %>% 
         group_by(MODEL)  %>% summarise_all(sum)

# put together 
rbind(df, first, second) 

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   MODEL total_value total_frequency
 1 A              62              78
 2 B              54              83
 3 C              78              24
 4 D              38              13
 5 E              16              22
 6 F              75              52
 7 G              39              16
 8 H              13              16
 9 I              58              20
10 J              37              72
11 X             140             102
12 Z             129              87
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is a straightforward solution to the problem.

```
i1 <- df1$MODEL %in% c("A", "C")
total_value <- sum(df1$total_value[i1])
total_frequency <- sum(df1$total_frequency[i1])
df1 <- rbind(df1, data.frame(MODEL = "X", total_value, total_frequency))

i2 <- df1$MODEL %in% c("D", "E", "F")
total_value <- sum(df1$total_value[i2])
total_frequency <- sum(df1$total_frequency[i2])
df1 <- rbind(df1, data.frame(MODEL = "Z", total_value, total_frequency))

df1
#   MODEL total_value total_frequency
#1      A          62              78
#2      B          54              83
#3      C          78              24
#4      D          38              13
#5      E          16              22
#6      F          75              52
#7      G          39              16
#8      H          13              16
#9      I          58              20
#10     J          37              72
#11     X         140             102
#12     Z         129              87
```

It is also possible to write a function to avoid repeating the same code.

```
fun <- function(X, M, vals){
  i1 <- X$MODEL %in% vals
  total_value <- sum(X$total_value[i1])
  total_frequency <- sum(X$total_frequency[i1])
  rbind(X, data.frame(MODEL = M, total_value, total_frequency))
}

df1 <- fun(df1, M = "X", vals = c("A", "C"))
df1 <- fun(df1, M = "Z", vals = c("D", "E", "F"))
```